# Azure Custom API return data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, azure

So I have been starting to use Azure and found out about the Custom API's.  This is exactly what I want but am having problems with the return data from iOS.  When I use fiddler, data is perfect.  It is just when returning via xcode.  Here is what I have:

```
[self.client invokeAPI:@"pointsbygameperuser"
             body:nil
       HTTPMethod:@"GET"
       parameters:@{@"Id":item}
          headers:nil
       completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

           NSLog(@"Result Here");
}];
```

When I view the result, it shows result as:

result  __NSCFArray *   @"2 objects"    0x155aa590
and then when I inspect ech, it lists object 0 and object 1 but the are blank...as in nohting appears
      result:
             [0]
             [1]

I have looked everywhere for some example of someone using the Custom API with a return type of objects but cannot find one.  Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Geo...

Comment: Sample invokeAPI with object response [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/19/custom-api-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks.aspx). Scroll down to the iOS section.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one and more or less based mine off of it.  I do return the two objects, but as I said, they are blank.  Frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem.  Apparently when dealing with the InvokeAPI, it is not a good idea to rely upon the "debugger" to view the results.  Although the result was being returned with the number of correct objects, I was not seeing any data per object....but when I did a

```
      NSLog(@"result: %@", result)
```

All data was shown in JSON format.  I could then iterate through it and do what I want.